# The multi-part identifier could not be bound - GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I'm pretty new to SQL. I have this code that works without the final `GROUP BY` line. With it, I receive the `multi-part identifier could not be bound.` I need to `GROUP BY L1_DESC, L2_DESC and L3_DESC`, but cannot figure out where to put this in the code.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT d.*
,c.COL_DESC
--,v.VAL_N
,an.CUST_ACCT_NBR
,s.L1_DESC, s.L2_DESC, s.L3_DESC
FROM dbo.ECL_SEG101_DATA d
INNER JOIN (
SELECT SITE_ID
,max(SRC_BATCH_ID) AS SRC_BATCH_ID
FROM dbo.ECL_SEG101_DATA d
WHERE SRC_ID = 'K12'
GROUP BY SITE_ID) d1
       ON d1.SRC_BATCH_ID = d.SRC_BATCH_ID
       AND d1.SITE_ID = d.SITE_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.ECL_SEG002_EXT_DATA_VAR v
       ON d.SRC_BATCH_ID = v.LIST_ID
       AND d.SRC_REC_ID = v.ROW_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INS_REF006_ACCT an
          ON d.SITE_ID = an.LOC_KEY
INNER JOIN dbo.ECL_SEG101_SEGMENT s
      ON d.SITE_SEG_LVLS_ID = s.LVLS_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.ECL_SEG002_EXT_COL c
       ON v.COL_ID = c.COL_ID
WHERE d.Site_Data_Ord = '1') p
GROUP BY c.COL_DESC, an.CUST_ACCT_NBR, s.L1_DESC, s.L2_DESC, s.L3_DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have aliased the subselect as `p` yet your `GROUP BY` references `c.`, `an.` etc. None of these are valid aliases - only `p.` is.

Also you can't return `*` as the columns returned from `d.*` in the subselect are not part of the `GROUP BY`. You will need these to be aggregated somehow (`COUNT`, `SUM` etc.).

So you need:

```
SELECT p.COL_DESC, p.CUST_ACCT_NBR, p.L1_DESC, p.L2_DESC, p.L3_DESC 
--, SOME_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION()
FROM (
    SELECT d.*
    ,c.COL_DESC
    --,v.VAL_N
    ,an.CUST_ACCT_NBR
    ,s.L1_DESC, s.L2_DESC, s.L3_DESC
    FROM dbo.ECL_SEG101_DATA d
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT SITE_ID
        ,max(SRC_BATCH_ID) AS SRC_BATCH_ID
        FROM dbo.ECL_SEG101_DATA d
        WHERE SRC_ID = 'K12'
        GROUP BY SITE_ID) d1
    ON d1.SRC_BATCH_ID = d.SRC_BATCH_ID
    AND d1.SITE_ID = d.SITE_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.ECL_SEG002_EXT_DATA_VAR v
    ON d.SRC_BATCH_ID = v.LIST_ID
    AND d.SRC_REC_ID = v.ROW_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INS_REF006_ACCT an
    ON d.SITE_ID = an.LOC_KEY
    INNER JOIN dbo.ECL_SEG101_SEGMENT s
    ON d.SITE_SEG_LVLS_ID = s.LVLS_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.ECL_SEG002_EXT_COL c
    ON v.COL_ID = c.COL_ID
    WHERE d.Site_Data_Ord = '1') p
GROUP BY p.COL_DESC, p.CUST_ACCT_NBR, p.L1_DESC, p.L2_DESC, p.L3_DESC
```